# CSS skew transform in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-7, css-transforms

I am trying to skey the headers of a table using CSS.
It works ok in IE9 but in IE7, the headers are skewed, but clipped.

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sWVrM/3/

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><p>ABD</p></th>
            <th><p>QWE</p></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table thead tr th {
    background: #ebf6fe;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    outline: 2px solid;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=-0.9999999999999977, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand');
}

table thead tr th p {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-1, M12=1.2246467991473532e-16, M21=-1.2246467991473532e-16, M22=-1, SizingMethod='auto expand');
    background-color: #ebf6fe;
}
```

I have tried setting the width, min-width, adding padding... but nothing works!

Also, the outline does not get skewed. If anyone knows how to do that too that would be great!

Comment: check for browser support here [css3_skew](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

Comment: I am using filters beacuse CSS3 is not supported by IE7.

Comment: https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/cssSandpaper

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't use third party plugins :(

Comment: @DON 1) please read questions more thoroughly 2) please don't propose w3schools links ([Reason](http://w3fools.com/))

Comment: according to the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014(v=vs.85).aspx) one should use padding to reduce the risk of clipping. But if you said this didn't help I don't know what to do. For Border and Outline not working your only chance is to introduce a second element beneath your `td` which is 2px wider on each side and apply the same transformation to it.

Comment: @Christoph Hey.. thanks! The clipping got avoided by adding another `<th></th>` tag in the end. I got the idea from your suggestion for the outline! :) But for the outline, i need it to have an outline even for the individual cells, not just the whole header.. any ideas?